# Getting error message during use of getLocation() function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, android-gps

When I use `getLocation()` function for multiple times, Android studio gives me the error message `Can't Get Your Location`. 
I always put the GPS activated on my testing device.

Please help me,I am new to Android Studio and Java.
forgive me for my English, It isn't my native language.

```
//location
private void getLocation() {

    //Check Permissions again
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {
        Location LocationGps= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location LocationNetwork=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Location LocationPassive=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

        if (LocationGps !=null)
        {
            double lat=LocationGps.getLatitude();
            double longi=LocationGps.getLongitude();

            latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude=String.valueOf(longi);
            showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            loc="http://www.google.com/maps/place/"+latitude+","+longitude;
        }
        else if (LocationNetwork !=null)
        {
            double lat=LocationNetwork.getLatitude();
            double longi=LocationNetwork.getLongitude();

            latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude=String.valueOf(longi);
            showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            loc="http://www.google.com/maps/place/"+latitude+","+longitude;

        }
        else if (LocationPassive !=null)
        {
            double lat=LocationPassive.getLatitude();
            double longi=LocationPassive.getLongitude();

            latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
            longitude=String.valueOf(longi);
            showLocationTxt.setText("Your Location:"+"\n"+"Latitude= "+latitude+"\n"+"Longitude= "+longitude);
            loc="http://www.google.com/maps/place/"+latitude+","+longitude;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Get Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This link should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747349/getlastknownlocation-return-null-using-gps-provider-and-network-provider

Comment: could you tell us the exact error message in the LogCat?